# Passing values from a form to a new action

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, action

Ok guys i have a question, if this is my Form , and is generated for every item in the DB, i want to send the item with the quantity specified.

to send the quantity , from this razor view

`@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Prices"))`
  `{`
   `string qtname = "qt" + @item.id;`
    `<div>
    <input id="@qtname" name="@qtname" class="quantity" type="text" value="0" readonly="readonly" />`

```
</div> 
<input type="submit" value="Adauga" class="addToCart" />`
```

}

i need just these?

`[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddToCart(ProductsModel Products, string qtname)
        { }`
and do i need some html.hidden for passing along the item.id too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form you are sending only the `qtname` parameter as input field, whereas your controller action also expects a `ProductsModel` parameter which is never sent. If you want to bind it you will have to create input fields for all properties of this view model.

But in your case a better solution would be to simply include the `id` of the product as hidden field and then fetch the corresponding product from your datastore given this id:

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult AddToCart(string id, string qtname) 
{ 
    ProductsModel products = _repository.GetProduct(id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: ok another problem that i haven't figure out and couldn't find to many links about it. How do i actually bind a entity (like Products) from my DB to a model ( ProductsModel )? I have a edmx and i usually use the

`db = new Data.EntityFramework.liftconEntities();`

and then create a dynamic model. i haven't figure out how to work with models